# More JQuery/Ajax and when/done/promise confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Once again I struggle with ajax calls - this time around some chaining issue. Overall here is what I need to accomplish:
I loop over some array, and for each item in the array, I need to do the following:
Issue an Ajax call, and upon success, I need to issue three other calls, which must be chained, so they run in sequence.

When all the items in the array have both their main call and the three chained subcalls completed, I must be able to do some action.

My problem is, that the program does not wait for the three chained subcalls to complete. In the code below, this can be seen by the "Done" statement in the log turns up before the subcalls have completed.

I have created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/LeifFrederiksen/td534phz/1/

Note: I have two different function for the addAttachments function (addAttachments and addAttachmentsAlternative) - none of them works like they should.

```
var items = ["A","B"];

save();

function doneSaving() {
  log("<H1>Done</H1>");
}

function save() {
    // Save all items, and do something when all is done...
  log("<H1>Save initiated</H1>");

  var returnValue = saveItems();
  $.when(returnValue).done(function() {
    doneSaving();
  })
}

function saveItems() {
    // Loop through all items and save each of them...
  var requests = Array();

  // Build array of requests to wait for...
  for (item of items) {
    requests.push(saveOneItem(item));
  }


   var returnValue = $.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
        log("All requests completed");
   })

  return returnValue;
}

function saveOneItem(item) {
  // Save one item...
  return addListItem(item,addListItemSuccess,addListItemFailure);
}

function addListItem(item, successFunction, failureFunction) {
   // The actual ajax that handles saving to database (actually Sharepoint via REST)...

   log("addListItem on: " + item);

    var returnValue = 
     $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",

        data: {html: item,
               delay: 1},

            }).done(function (data) {
            if (successFunction != undefined) {
                returnValue = successFunction(item, data); // Returns the newly created list item information
                return returnValue;
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            return failureFunction(item, data);
        });

    return returnValue;
}

function addListItemSuccess(item,data) {
    log("addListItem succces - in succes function for " + item);

    returnValue = addAttachmentsAlternative(item,data);
    return returnValue;
}

function addAttachments(item,data) {
  var attachment1Deferred = addListItem(item + "-attachment 1",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure);

  var attachment2Deferred = attachment1Deferred.then(
            function() {
               return addListItem(item + "-attachment 2",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure);
            });
     var attachment3Deferred = attachment2Deferred.then(
             function() {
               return addListItem(item + "-attachment 3",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure);
             });

    attachment3Deferred.done(
           function() {
             log("Completed upload of all attachments for " + item);
            })
    return attachment3Deferred;                                   
}

function addAttachmentsAlternative(item,data) {
 return addListItem(item + "-attachment 1",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure)
                        .done(function(data) {
                            return addListItem(item + "-attachment 2",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure)
            }).done(function(data) {
                            return addListItem(item + "-attachment 3",addAttachmentSuccess,addAttachmentFailure)
            }).done(function(data) {
                log("Completed alternative upload of all attachments for " + item);
            });
}    
function addAttachmentSuccess(item,data) {
    log("addAttachment succces - in succes function for " + item);
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred;
}

function addListItemFailure(item,data) {
    console.log("addListItem failed - calling failure function for " + item);
    $("#console").append("<P>addListItem failed - in failure function for " + item);
}

function addAttachmentFailure(item,data) {
    console.log("addListItem failed - calling failure function for " + item);
    $("#console").append("<P>addListItem failed - in failure function for " + item);
}

function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
    $("#console").append("<P>" + message);

}
```

I am hoping to achieve some generic pattern that I can use in different cases.

I got my inspiration from this great article, but cannot get it to work in my scenario: https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f#.tu0sruz5k

Any ideas and inputs are more than welcome.

Regards
Leif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the provided example:

- to chain the tasks of creating list items and adding attachments use
  `.then` instead of `.done`. With `.done` callback that prints `All requests completed` it is fired once deferred (first ajax call in `addListItem` function) is getting resolved.
- some functions like `addListItem` still uses callback function syntax, i would  suggest convert them to promises
- since all deferred are getting resolved in `saveItems` function there is no need to use `jQuery.when()` in `save` function

[**Modified demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/o7e4dgxc/)